# I want to get a pop-up notification when new value in inserted in my mysql database table using Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to show a successful message as notification in my home page when a new value is inserted into my database.

Controller

```
 function insert(Request $request)
{  
    $teacher = new teacher;

        $teacher->Teacher_name      =  $request->Teacher_name;
        $teacher->School_name       =  $request->School_name;
        $teacher->Date_of_Birth     =  $request->Date_of_Birth;

        $teacher->save();

  $teacher = teacher::find($request->id);
  return back()->with('success', 'Data inserted Successfully');
}
```

View

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span 
  class="label label-pill label-danger count" style="border- 
   radius:10px;"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" 
   style="font-size:18px;"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, you can show success or failure alerts using **Flash** as below,

Controller:

```
\Session::flash('success', 'Data inserted Successfully.');
```

Blade file:

```
@if ($message = \Session::get('success'))
  <div class="alert success-msg">
    {{ $message }}
  </div>
@endif
```

**UPDATE:**
To keep message in blade until closed;

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <strong>
            {!! session()->get('success') !!}
        </strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

**UPDATE:2**
To get real time notification, you can use Pusher and implementation guide for the same is: https://www.sitepoint.com/add-real-time-notifications-laravel-pusher/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to get a notification under my bell icon, not flash message

Comment: You can print message wherever needed. The page will be reloaded on insertion or you are using ajax?

Comment: yeah OK, but I want to hold those unread message under bell icon, until anyone viewed it. How can I do that?

Comment: This is working, but this is not the thing I wanted. I want to get notification like facebook whenever someone insert value from a website. I want to see success message in my admin dashboard under bell icon.

Comment: Okay. You can find here what you are looking for: https://www.sitepoint.com/add-real-time-notifications-laravel-pusher/

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this only.

Comment: Welcome. Keep coding. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use **Flash**,

Controller:

```
\Session::flash('success', 'Data inserted Successfully.');
```

Blade file:

```
 @if ($message = \Session::get('success'))
      <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>{{$message}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script> $('#myModal').modal('show');</script>
    @endif
```

Post this after you Load jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: yeah OK, but I want to hold those unread message under bell icon, until anyone viewed it. How can I do that?